# Providing specific access to the user and developer in the maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, profile

I have a maven plugin project where i need that the developers and the users will be the two profiles using this plugin. I needed to give certain privileges to the developers and to the users. Can i do this using profiles? If so can anybody explain me with example or refer a link which explains the same. I have been going through but i am not able to get it.
The developers will be adding the functionality and creating the jar file.
Where as users will be using the Jar file and provide input arguments when they execute the jar. 
If there is a better way to do it please suggest.
Thanks for your responses..

Comment: The users of a pom are developers ? Hm...i don't understand the intention of your questions. Can you explain a little bit more your intention what you like to achieve with this?

Comment: i have explained my intention. Let me know if u need further explanation. Thanks for ur help

Comment: Are you talking about the injected parameters of the configuration for a plugin or from the developers point of view the unit- or integration tests ?

Comment: No not injecting parameters. Once the jar is build by the developer. The user will be using the jar and provide input arguments. The input arguments should be in a file.

Comment: java -jar SampleProg ipFile.txt or xml  something similar if possible through maven or other option.

Comment: So you need something to create an executable (appassembler-maven-plugin) and have command line parameters (JCommander) ? Are we really talking about a maven-plugin project ? You are creating a maven-plugin ?

Comment: I don't need Jcommander. I think its getting complicated. So as of now what i have done is i am providing a input arg file which has the inputs. Thanks Khmarbaise for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally profiles allow you to activate different plugins or substitute different property values. For example that can be different urls for developers and users. Please see [Maven Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: Which kind of URLs should be different for developers and users?

Comment: @khmarbaise That is just an example. It could be any urls.